# Use plasTeX on short strings

Tags: html, python

I'm trying to find a python package which will convert short strings like

```
A closed-form solution of 
$\textbf{R}\textbf{R}_1=\textbf{R}_2\textbf{R}$
w.r.t $\textbf{R}$
```

to a reasonable HTML representation, like

```
A closed-form solution of 
<i><b>R</b><b>R<b><sub>1</sub> = <b>R</b><sub>2</sub> <b>R</b></i>
w.r.t <i><b>R</b></i>
```

No LaTeX packages or document layout commands (`\section` etc.) will be involved; just the subset of TeX allowed in stackexchange postings.

While [Mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) does handle this beautifully, unfortunately Javascript options are off the table, as this is for an email digest--it has to be static HTML output. Inline CSS is fine. I know there's a Node.js version of Mathjax that can approximate its output in static form (with a buhc of caveats about how the result won't be browser-responsive and other things I don't care about), but I want Python.

The best option I've found seems to be [plasTeX](http://tiarno.github.io/plastex/), but all the documentation there seems to be about converting whole .tex files to .html, or, for some reason, .xml files, which is much more than I want to do.

I suppose, if need be, I could generate temporary .html files and then use BeautifulSoup to parse out only the part I'm interested in, but this seems a bit silly. Since I'm talking about doing this maybe 50 times per script invocation, this would certainly be doable.

Is there a simple way to use plasTeX or any other python package to get html equivalents of short latex snippets?

Comment: I honestly think you should ask this in a community that is about Python or general programming questions not about TeX.

Comment: @Skillmon Yeah, I considered that, but decided that the question is more knowledge-based than anything about Python in particular. I'm essentially asking an XY question. I could migrate it elsewhere if you have a suggestion.

Comment: Stackoverflow. That seems like the right place to me.

Comment: @Skillmon It seems I don't have enough reputation to do this; if you can, could you please migrate it for me?

Answer (score 0):

You may find https://github.com/alvinwan/TexSoup useful. Using this library, you could replace the boldfaced parts in two lines. Although a sufficient number of regexes could do, TexSoup gives you a bit more flexibility.

```
from TexSoup import TexSoup
soup = TexSoup(r"$\textbf{R}\textbf{R}_1=\textbf{R}_2\textbf{R}$")

for b in soup.find_all('textbf'):
    b.replace("<b>{args[0]}</b>".format(args=b.args))
```